# return type of cin.get()

Tags: c++, loops, conditional-statements

i have problem understanding the following code

```
    for (i = 0; i < ArSize; i++) 
    { 
        cout << i+1 << “: “; 
        cin.get(temp, MaxLen); 
        while (cin && cin.get() != ‘\n’) 
            continue; 
        if (!cin || temp[0] == ‘\0’)    
            break;             
        else 
            sayings[i] = temp;  
}
```

my question is when is the while loop terminated?
please explain to me what does while loop do in this program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop is checking whether the stream object, `cin`, is in good state or not and then skipping anything till new line.

Stream objects define a conversion to bool which is only true when the stream is not in error state.